# Connectedness implies there exists a k for all z? (obtained from John B. Conway)

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness

This is obtained from Functions of one complex variable by John B. Conway P.39

Let $f$ be a given branch of the logarithm on the connected set G and suppose $k$ is an integer. Put $g(z)=f(z)+2\pi ki$ and $h(z)={1\over 2\pi i}[f(z)-g(z)]$, then $h$ is continuous on $G$ and $h(G)$ is connected. Hence there is a $k$ in $\Bbb Z$ with $f(z)+2\pi ki=g(z)$ for all $z$ in $G$

I have trouble in understanding why connectedness implies "Hence there is a $k$ in $\Bbb Z$ with $f(z)+2\pi ki=g(z)$ for all $z$ in $G$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $h$ is continuous and integer-valued, hence constant. (Or if you want to argue exactly as in your quote, the only connected subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ are single points.)